# Showing that $(I : J) : K = I : JK$ for polynomial ideals $I, J, K \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $I, J, K \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be polynomial ideals. I am trying to show that  $(I : J) : K = I : JK$, where the quotient of ideals $I, J \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is defined as $I:J = \{f \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\mid \forall g \in J.fg \in I\}$.

Currently I am stuck at arguing why the quantifiers for the two sets $(I : J) : K$ and $I : JK$ are equal. For $(I : J) : K$ we have that $f \in (I : J) : K \Longleftrightarrow \forall g \in K. fg \in I:J \Longleftrightarrow \forall g \in K. \forall h \in J. fgh \in I$. And for $I : JK$ we have that $f \in I:JK \Longleftrightarrow \forall p \in JK.fp \in I$.

Inclusion $(I : J) : K \subseteq I : JK$ follows almost by definition, but for the reverse inclusion, if I am not mistaken, I would have to show that any product $p = \sum_{i=1}^la_ib_i, a_i \in J, b_i \in K, i = 1,\dots,l$ can be written as a product between two elements $f \in J, g \in K$, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This property holds in general: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802158

Comment: @John doesn't the linked answer assume that every element in $JK$ is on the form $jk$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Certainly not.